# Python: Retain user input and only address those that fail validation

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I use tkinter optionmenu to obtain user input. I have several of it (about 6 or 7). I am tying to create validation for these 6 or 7 optionmenu. It cannot be blank.
If blank, then request for input again.
I have the below codes (for 2 optionmenu as example):

```
def validate_input(self):
    prod = self.prod_var.get()
    year = self.year_var.get()
    while True:
        if (prod == "") | (year ==""):
            messagebox.showinfo('Records Validation', "Please check your entries. Please enter all fields.", icon='warning')
        break
```

The code works but I would like to have the field that already have data retain as is. With the above code, once the "OK" button is clicked on the messagebox, all optionmenu selection is blank. User need to re-enter.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: It seems impossible for the code you posted to reset the optionmenus, since there's no code to do that.

Comment: It did reset the optionmenu (all of it). I don't now why and I don't want it to do so...

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: By the looks of the code you aren't storing the state of that optionmenu anywhere.  You would need to store the optionmenu state in order to prevent it being wiped.  Are you creating the option menu inside a loop or something?